# Using a Keyboard in a 556 Stepped Tone Generator

Tags: integrated-circuit, sound, keyboard

I'm in the process of making a simple stepped tone generator using the 556 timer, but I want to be able to have different resistors to change the pitch of the tone I get out. I think it would be really nifty to repurpose an old computer keyboard to act as the switch between these different resistors to cause different pitches, but I'm not sure where to start when it comes to getting the computer to bridge between different resistances or traces.

[image: simple stepped tone generator]

Comment: What is your level of electronics and/or programming?

Comment: Not very high. I'm a Mechanical Engineering Student and I have the stepped tone generator working with some photoresistors like a theremin. I would love to be able to integrate a keyboard though.

Comment: Compared to the tone generator circuit that would be a huge undertaking. The best you could try is to isolate the switches in the keyboard and to use them to select different values for R (or R3, but not both). This would render they beyboard useless for other purposes.